# jQuery get a comma delimited list of fields with certain class

Tags: jquery

Im trying to get a comma delimited list of field names with a class that are dynamically created.

My end goal is to get appliance_1,appliance_2,appliance_3 inside a hidden field

```
<input type="hidden" name="tracker" id="appliance-tracker" value="appliance_1,appliance_2,appliance_3">

<input class="appliances" name="appliance_1">
<input class="appliances" name="appliance_2">
<input class="appliances" name="appliance_3">
<script>
$("#btn").click(function(){
$("#appliance-tracker").val($("input.appliances").serialize());
});
</script>
```

it keeps setting the value as 
appliance_1=&appliance_2=&appliance_3=

Is there an easy way to do this that im completely missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/)

```js
var text = $("input.appliances").map(function() {
    return $(this).attr('name');
  })
  .get() //returns basic array
  .join(','); //create a string

console.log(text)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="appliances" name="appliance_1">
<input class="appliances" name="appliance_2">
<input class="appliances" name="appliance_3">
```